# How to work with Subsonic MySQL in ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1

What are the requirements and how to work with subsonic in ASP.NET Core 3.1 or later versions?
How to build DAL using subsonic in ASP.NET Core 3.1?
What is the use of SubSonic.Core.DAL 4.2.1?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: SubSonic is dead since long time, isn't it?